# How can I check text content with respect to display:none style

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, dom, angularjs-directive

I would like to get text content of a DOM node, but without elements that are effectively hidden (have style `display:none`).

I know about DOM `textContent` property and jQuery's `text()` method (I think it uses `textContent` anyway), but it doesn't respect `display:none`:

```
var div = $("<div><span style='display:none'>not </span>good</div>");
var text = div.text(); // "not good"
var textContent = div[0].textContent; // "not good"
```

How can I get just `"good"` content from that div?

I need this unit test my AngularJS directive. I am writing tests using Jasmine and my test is something similar to that:

```
    it('should check text ignoring hidden content', function() {
      $rootScope.hidden = true;
      var template = '<div><span ng-hide="hidden">not </span>good<div>';
      var element = $compile(template)($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();

      console.debug(element.html());    // prints: '<span class="ng-hide" ng-hide="hidden">not </span>good<div></div>'
      console.debug(element.text());    // prints: 'not good'
      expect(element.text()).toEqual('good');   // oops, that fails :(
});
```

In my real test I want to test my custom directive instead of `ng-hide`, but the actual directive is irrelvant for that question.

I am completely new to Jasmine and Javascript unit testing, so please also let me know if this is just not the way to go.

Comment: @LShetty Did you even understand the question? It's a matter of having a universal solution, not about this specific case.

Comment: Oops! ended up deleting my comment. @Nit, I know what you mean. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @TMG **good** is not in `span` tag it is by mistake or your needs.

Comment: If it is by mistake then this will work for you `var text = $("#test span:visible").text();`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6dLxywxn/

Comment: doesn't seem like a very practical test in the first place

Comment: @Sadikhasan I do not want to make any assumptions about the content in my test, so `<span>` cannot be expected.

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few considerations to keep in mind: you can use `clone()` to avoid modifying the original object, however to use `:visible`, the elements have to actually be in the DOM.

```js
var sample = $("<div><span style='display:none'>not </span>good <div>content</div></div>");
var t = sample.clone();
$('body').append(t);
t.find('*:not(:visible)').remove();
t.remove();
alert(t.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to work exactly the way I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

if you apply a class for your style like .noDisplay { display:none; } you could do something like div.find('span.noDisplay').remove(); with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try The following.
It will get the text of only "Visible" spans.

```js
  
  
  var text="";
   $("#content-div").find('span:visible').each(function(){         
       text=text+' '+$(this).text();         
   });
  
  alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="content-div"><span >ok</span> <span style="display:none">hidden</span></div>
```

Comment: Check `<div><span style='display:none'>not </span>good</div>`  **good** is not in `span` tag.

Comment: If it is in `span` tag then `var text = $("#content-div span:visible").text(); ` It is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('div').find('span').text("").parent().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, no one mentions about the other attribute `innerText` which "is aware of styling and won't return the text of "hidden" elements" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). This can be a one-line fix by just replacing `textContent` to `innerText`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery `remove()` function and apply to the div children element.

Add `div.children().remove();` right after `var div = $("<div><span style='display:none'>not </span>good</div>");` and you will get only "good" content

Comment: This is not a generic answer.

Comment: @Nit, thank you for the comment. My mistake didn't see the full question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to filter the contents and you should target the `nodeType = 3` which is assigned for [`TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
var div = $("<div><span style='display:none'>not </span>good</div>");
   
var textContent = div.contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).get(0).textContent; // "good"

$('body').html(textContent); // logs "good"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```